# Помогите починить таблицу

Tags: python, pandas

Я имею экселевский файл с таблицей данных, при открытии её в питоне большинство ячеек заполнено NaN и как это разрешить я не понимаю.
Прикрепляю скриншот, как она выглядит в экселе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И прикрепляю ссылку на сам экселевский файл - [ссылка на файл](https://dropmefiles.com/qxdc9)

Comment: НаНы из-за а) объединения ячеек, б) множества пустых ячеек, на которых сверху расположены графики

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вашего случая, если формат файла одинаков, можно попробовать так:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("загрузка клуба.xlsx", skiprows=8)

df = df[df["Дата день"].str.contains("^\d\d\.", na=False)]
df = df.set_index("Дата день")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
df = df.dropna(how="all", axis=1)
df.columns=["Клиентов за день", "Пиковая нагрузка - время", "Пиковая нагрузка - количество", "Среднее время в клубе"]
```

df:

```
            Клиентов за день Пиковая нагрузка - время Пиковая нагрузка - количество Среднее время в клубе
Дата день                                                                                                
2023-12-01             285.0                    20:41                           124           2 ч. 5 мин.
2023-12-02             496.0                    19:07                           137           2 ч. 4 мин.
2023-12-03             486.0                    20:03                           147          2 ч. 25 мин.
2023-12-04             254.0                    19:48                            64           2 ч. 3 мин.
2023-12-05             190.0                    19:55                            68           2 ч. 3 мин.
2023-12-06             235.0                    21:07                            63           2 ч. 3 мин.
2023-12-07             206.0                    20:41                            72          2 ч. 22 мин.
2023-12-08             267.0                    20:49                           100          1 ч. 55 мин.
2023-12-09             451.0                    18:39                           138          2 ч. 19 мин.
2023-12-10             384.0                    19:30                           103          2 ч. 11 мин.
2023-12-11             218.0                    20:04                            78          2 ч. 14 мин.
2023-12-12             252.0                    20:27                            83          2 ч. 35 мин.
2023-12-13             254.0                    16:48                            71           2 ч. 8 мин.
2023-12-14             263.0                    16:41                            73          2 ч. 14 мин.
2023-12-15             241.0                    20:23                            96          3 ч. 13 мин.
2023-12-16             425.0                    19:32                           139          2 ч. 17 мин.
2023-12-17             369.0                    17:27                           120          2 ч. 14 мин.
2023-12-18             256.0                    20:30                            83          2 ч. 16 мин.
2023-12-19             185.0                    20:41                            63          2 ч. 14 мин.
2023-12-20             255.0                    19:26                            83          2 ч. 14 мин.
2023-12-21             238.0                    20:25                            87          2 ч. 20 мин.
2023-12-22             277.0                    20:47                            88          2 ч. 12 мин.
2023-12-23             347.0                    18:34                           111          2 ч. 29 мин.
2023-12-24             427.0                    19:17                           127          2 ч. 16 мин.
2023-12-25             269.0                    20:27                            73          2 ч. 10 мин.
2023-12-26             115.0                    15:57                            62          1 ч. 46 мин.
```

Comment: Вау, сильно признателен за помощь, сам бы не разобрался.